# How to avoid transparency behind the volumetric world shader?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I have a volumetric shader set up for the World.

[image]

But when I render, I see a transparent background behind where the density is too low.

[image]

Is there a way to remove transparency and add a background color or texture instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in "Render Properties > Film" and make sure Transparent is unchecked.

[image]

If you want to add a background color, but not have it affect the lighting of the scene you can hookup "Camera Ray" from the Light Path node to a mix shader.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The "Camera Ray" approach is very interesting!